# Verify video encoding is H.264

Tags: java, h.264, aac, xuggle, xuggler

I need to verify that a video file is (in Java):

- Video is H.264 Encoded
- Audio is AAC Encoded

I've looked into JMF and Xuggle.

Xuggle makes it easier to load and decode the file and turn it into another format, but I've not been able to figure out how to determine the encoding of the file that I've loaded as of yet.

So Im wondering if Xuggle has the capability to simply return the type of Video & Audio encoding a file has or do I need to read the bits of the file to determine this myself?

If I need to determine this myself, can someone point me to some documention on the format of H.264

Comment: Why does this matter to your application? Do these codec restrictions imply other, unspecified requirements about [container format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_container_formats), [H.264 profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC#Profiles), or [AAC profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_3#Audio_Profiles)?

Comment: This is just the ensure we don't get trouble makers uploading images or text files as Video files. It is only a precaution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I looked at Xuggler's Decoding Demo and found my answer, so for anyone in the future looking for a similar solution here is the code I wrote:

---

```
    // create a Xuggler container object
    IContainer container = IContainer.make();
    if(container.open(file.getPath(),IContainer.Type.READ,null) < 0) {
        return false;
    }

    // query how many streams the call to open found
    boolean isH264 = false;
    boolean isAAC = false;

    int numStreams = container.getNumStreams();
    for(int i = 0; i < numStreams; i++)
    {
      // find the stream object
      IStream stream = container.getStream(i);
      // get the pre-configured decoder that can decode this stream;
      IStreamCoder coder = stream.getStreamCoder();

      if (coder.getCodecID() == ID.CODEC_ID_H264)  {
          isH264 = true;
      }
      if (coder.getCodecID() == ID.CODEC_ID_AAC)  {
          isAAC = true;
      }
    }

    if (container !=null)
    {
      container.close();
      container = null;
    }
    return isH264 && isAAC;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is couple of lines with JCodec ( http://jcodec.org ):

```
MovieBox movie = MP4Util.parseMovie(new File("path to file"));
Assert.assertEquals(movie.getVideoTrack().getSampleEntries()[0].getFourcc(), "avc1");
for (TrakBox trakBox : movie.getAudioTracks()) {
    Assert.assertEquals(trakBox.getSampleEntries()[0].getFourcc(), "mp4a");
}
```